# Take an unknown format string and return a UTF-8 string

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

The following two strings are different in format but identical in data:

```
str1 = '\xd7\x91\xd7\xa8\xd7\xa7'
str2 = u'\u05d1\u05e8\u05e7'
```

I need to implement the following function:

- Take a string in either one of the formats above as input
- Return the equivalent string in the first format as output

I know that I can encode a string from the second format into the first format.

But how do I determine that the input string is indeed given in the second format?

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus: Converting to unicode is exactly what I **don't** want to do. It's converting from unicode that I'm interested in.

Comment: Well, that's really the same question in reverse… The reason this isn't a duplicate is that you're explicitly dealing with UTF-8, while that question is about the case when you don't know what you're dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python 3.x, the right thing to do would probably be to `try` to call `encode`. (For 3.5+, this [will hopefully](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0463/) be as simple as `try s.encode('utf-8') except AttributeError: s`.)

But for 2.x, the `encode` will succeed even on `str1`—by first decoding the UTF-8 string as ASCII (or whatever `sys.getdefaultencoding()` returns) so it can re-encode it, so you definitely don't want that.

When there is no way to safely [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp), you have no choice but to [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl). So:

```
if isinstance(s, unicode):
    return s.encode('utf-8')
else:
    return s
```

---

Note that I'm using [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) here, not calling `type` and comparing. As [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) says:

> Object type comparisons should always use `isinstance()` instead of comparing types directly.

Why? Because instances of subtypes (subclasses, classes registered with ABCs, etc.) are, by definition, supposed to always count as instances of their supertypes. There are some rare cases where you explicitly need to break that rule, in which case `type` comparisons are what you want. But otherwise, don't use them.

Comment: Thanks. What about checking if `type(input) == 'str'`? Would you consider that as a good approach?

Comment: @barakmanos: No. First, `'str'` and `str` are not equal, so that will never be true. Second, `isinstance` is almost always better than comparing types; the only reason to ever do the latter is when you explicitly want to break the usual rule about subclasses being substitutable for base classes.

Comment: Sorry, but you've got me completely confused. In your answer you suggest something, and then summarize it with "so you definitely don't want that". Then, you suggest an alternative to which you later refer in the comment above with "the only reason to ever do that...". So what exactly do you propose as the best approach here?

Comment: @barakmanos: I'm proposing `isinstance`. You definitely don't want to just call `.encode` blindly. And you don't want to use `type(…) ==`. So use `isinstance`. I've edited the answer to try to make that clearer.